# Why is my graph not showing every Month? Facetgrid, Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, facet-grid

My **sample dataset** is the following:

```py
dataset = {
    "ClientId": [
        10, 20, 20, 20, 10, 5, 3, 7, 5, 20, 12, 5, 
        3, 20, 5, 8, 10, 9, 7, 20, 21, 5, 3, 10,
    ],
    "Year": [
        2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019,
        2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020,
        2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020,
    ],
    "Month": [
        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", 
        "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", 
        "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec",
    ],
    "Sector": [
        "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
        "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C",
    ],
    "Quantity": [
        100, 50, 25, 30, 40, 50, 200, 600, 20, 40, 100, 20, 50, 
        400, 250, 300, 125, 75, 90, 10, 225, 550, 450, 55,     
    ],     
    "Regions": [
        "Europe", "Asia", "Africa", "Africa", "Other", "Asia", 
        "Africa", "Other", "America", "America", "Europe", 
        "Europe", "Other", "Europe", "Asia", "Africa", "Asia", 
        "Europe", "Other", "Africa", "Europe", "Asia", "Africa", 
        "Europe",
    ],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)
```

I want to produce a `Facetgrid` of bar plots for each Year and Sector.
I have managed to create the plot:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='Year', row='Sector', margin_titles=True)
g.map_dataframe(sns.barplot, x='Month', y='Quantity', color='orange')
g.set_axis_labels('Months','Quantity')
```

**The Problem:** The bar plots don't display every Months, only a few. What I would like is to see one bar per Month but I'm stuck.

The graph looks like this currently:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force seaborn to use all the columns by providing the column `order` to `map_dataframe`:

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Year", row="Sector", margin_titles=True)
g.map_dataframe(
    sns.barplot, x="Month", y="Quantity", color="orange", order=df["Month"].unique()
)
g.set_axis_labels("Months", "Quantity")
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
```

---

Alternatively, and a better option in my opinion, is to use [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) like so. This still returns a facetgrid, but doesn't require extra fiddling.

```py
g = sns.catplot(
    x="Month",
    y="Quantity",
    col="Year",
    row="Sector",
    data=df,
    kind="bar",
    height=2.5,
    aspect=0.8,
    color="orange",
    margin_titles=True,
)
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
```

Which produces:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, indeed catplot is much better. But when I run catplot in my actual dataset I have a black line that appears just as in the barplot documentation[ (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html#seaborn.barplot). Do you know how I can remove that?

Comment: Those are error bars, you can remove them by adding `ci=None` to the `catplot` function call